# Losing plus sign in native JPA query

Tags: jpa, jboss, switchyard

I have a native sql query in a switchyard project

```
(select sysdate + interval '720' minute from dual)
```

However, when the jboss server executes the query the plus sign has disappeared from the trace

```
(select sysdate   interval '720' minute from dual)
```

How can I escape the plus sign so it appears as part of my native query.